# How to access the mainWindow from another script in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, modal-dialog, electron

My electron app defines the `BrowserWindow` *mainWindow* in the *main.js*. It loads an html and eventually inside of the html a script runs the function [`dialog.showMessageBox()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options-callback) which displays a simple warning:

```
dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'warning',
    message: "You have been warned.",
    buttons: ["OK"]
});
```

I want this dialog to be a child of the *mainWindow* b/c that makes it a modal, which disables the *mainWindow* until it is closed. To implement this you normally would just add `mainWindow,`before the type declaration. Unfortunately it doesn't know the variable *mainWindow* since the [`dialog.showMessageBox()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options-callback) is created in a different script (*site.js*).

How can I create a dialog, that is a child of the *mainWindow* without creating it in the *main.js*? 
Can [ipc](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) help somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accepted answer is still correct, but quite old, and in the meantime the Electron team decided to slowly deprecate the `remote` module (more info [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) and [here](https://nornagon.medium.com/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31)):

[image]

---

However, I was able to fix it by using `BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()`, which makes only one tiny assumption that the window which triggers the MsgBox is the one being currently focused (my guess is that in 99% of the cases that's true). Here's the updated code:

```
const { dialog, BrowserWindow } = require ("electron");

dialog.showMessageBox (BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), {
  type: "warning",
  message: "You have been warned.",
  buttons: ["OK"]
});
```

Comment: However, this has to run on the main process and not in the renderer.

Answer (score 12):

#### Current Electron versions (>= 14.0.0)

Starting with Electron 14.0.0, the below-mentioned `remote` module has been [deprecated and subsequently removed](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-14-0). In order to still open these dialog boxes from the renderer process, I suggest to send a message to the main process via IPC:

```js
// renderer process
const { ipcRenderer  } = require ("electron");

ipcRenderer.send ("show-message");
```

And the listening part in the main process:

```js
// main process
const { dialog, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require ("electron");

ipcMain.on ("show-message", (event, args) => {
    dialog.showMessageBox (BrowserWindow.fromWebContents (event.sender), {
        type: "warning",
        message: "You have been warned.",
        buttons: ["OK"]
    });
});
```

This will open the message box as a modal dialog for the `BrowserWindow` instance which has sent the IPC message and will thus work as a drop-in replacement for the `remote` code.

---

#### Electron < 14.0.0

You can use Electron's [`remote`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) module to get your current `BrowserWindow` from the script included (loaded) in that window:

```js
const remote = require ("electron").remote;

dialog.showMessageBox (remote.getCurrentWindow (), {
  type: "warning",
  message: "You have been warned.",
  buttons: ["OK"]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To safely get the mainWindow in electron, I store its ID in a env variable and call `BrowserWindow.fromId(ID)` when needed.

`BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()` will not work in some case, for exemple if you load an URL from a child window to the main window.
I met some weird effect too, with `BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()` solution.

```
// store the ID at init time when you create your main window
process.env.MAIN_WINDOW_ID = mainWindow.id;
```

```
// every time you want the main window, call this function.
// don't forget to convert the env variable to type number otherwise this will throw an error.
const getMainWindow = () => {
  const ID = process.env.MAIN_WINDOW_ID * 1;
  return BrowserWindow.fromId(ID)
}
```